# How to improve speed of getting data from SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC (dupe)

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I am new to asp.net mvc5.

I have a model `Shipping` and my `dbo.Shippings.sql` is shown here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shippings] 
(
    [Id]                INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TrackingNumber]    NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FromCompany]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [FromContactName]   NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [From]              NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FromCity]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FromState]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FromZipCode]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FromCountry]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FromPhoneNumber]   NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [FromFaxNumber]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Commodity]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [OrderDateTime]     DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [OrderByName]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [PickUpDateTime]    DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [PickUpRefNum]      NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [DestCompany]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [DestContactName]   NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Destination]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [DestCity]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [DestState]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [DestZipCode]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [DestCountry]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [DestPhoneNumber]   NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [DestFaxNumber]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [DeliveryDateTime]  DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [Price]             FLOAT (53)      NOT NULL,
    [Category]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [FreightClass]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [Pkgs]              INT             NOT NULL,
    [Weight]            REAL            NOT NULL,
    [Length]            REAL            NOT NULL,
    [Width]             REAL            NOT NULL,
    [Height]            REAL            NOT NULL,
    [IsDelivered]       BIT             NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationUserId] NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
    [AcceptOffer]       BIT             DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [TruckerId]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Description]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [FileName]          NVARCHAR (255)  NULL,
    [ContentType]       NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,
    [Content]           VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Shippings]  
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Shippings_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUserId]) 
            REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApplicationUserId]
    ON [dbo].[Shippings]([ApplicationUserId] ASC);
```

And my first page must shows all shippings that not sold (`if shipping.truckerId == null` means not sold yet)

In my `ShippingController` I have below:

```
// GET: Shipping
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        //below is sorting
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.FromSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "from_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DestSortParm = sortOrder == "Destination" ? "dest_desc" : "Destination";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        //below is searching state and zipcode
        var shippings = from s in db.Shippings
                        where s.TruckerId == null
                        select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            shippings = shippings.Where(s => s.FromState.Contains(searchString)//from state
                                   || s.DestState.Contains(searchString)//dest state
                                   || s.FromZipCode.Contains(searchString)//from zipcode
                                   || s.DestZipCode.Contains(searchString));//dest zipcode
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "from_desc":
                shippings = shippings.OrderByDescending(s => s.From);
                break;
            case "Destination":
                shippings = shippings.OrderBy(s => s.Destination); //not working
                break;
            case "dest_desc":
                shippings = shippings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Destination); //not working
                break;
            default:
                shippings = shippings.OrderByDescending(s => s.OrderDateTime);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(shippings.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        //return View(shippings.ToList());

    }
```

I think:

```
var shippings = from s in db.Shippings
                where s.TruckerId == null
                select s;
```

is not clever way to get shippings and it is very slow if the db gets bigger..

Please help!

Comment: You have many `nvarchar(max)` columns... why?

Comment: @SqlZim I just set them `string` didn't give restriction. Shoud I give them max value?

Comment: I don't think your real problem is in that code you suggested. I think is in those contains. That's a real cost to analyze all those values. One question: are you really showing ALL those columns in the view?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso No I only shows its `FromCity`, `FromState`, `FromZipCode`, `PickUpDateTime`, `DestCity`, `DestState`, `DestZipCode`, `Price`, `Content`, and `TruckerId` which tells it is sold or not.

Comment: Then, the first thing i would recommend, is to retrieve only the needed columns on that select, and adapt the view to access only that object. One  thing you might have to consider is, if you indeed have a lot of values, it might take some time to load the pagedList. So to reduce that, access the database with only the values that are being requested in the list.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso I not quite understand your answer.. Could you please show me sample code like this?:`var shippings = from s in db.Shippings
                            where s.TruckerId == null
                            select s;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you need to review your datatypes. Its just not feasible that you actually need that many `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns. So the first thing is to reshape the database in that sense. I highly recommend you to have a look at Joe Celko's [Stairway to Data](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72899/) series over SQL Server Central, it will give you a clear picture of datatypes and their correct usage.

On the other hand if you want to get only some fields from that using LINQ you could go with something like:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
     var theDataINeed = (from myData in ctx.Shipping
                        where myData.TruckerId == null
                        select new {
                           myData.FromCity,
                           myData.FromState,
                           myData.FromZipCode,
                           myData.PickUpDateTime
                        });
}
```

Then you pass it to a `List<>` or so and you'll get only what you need.